# AEM 6.5.2 to Mulesoft integration

Tags: rest, osgi, adobe, jcr, aem-6

I am new to AEM and need suggestions. We have a requirement where i have to post each notifications in the inbox /libs/cq/workflow/content/inbox/list.json to mulesoft via rest api. I thought of below:

1. Write a custom maven project and deploy on AEM as package
2. Edit existing workflows to add a new step which will call this class
3. When called, this will post a rest api request to mulesoft

Is this a right way to do or do you suggest any other better way. Please let me know.

Comment: I think you mean that the AEM project has to make a request to an application, deployed in some of MuleSoft products, which implements a REST API. Remember that MuleSoft is a company, not a product or a REST API.

Comment: Hello Aled, thank you for your response. AEM is an Adobe CMS. So it’s a product. Mulesoft is a company which has its product https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/rest-api-examples.. so I am not sure what you meant but I am new to both the tools. If my terminology is wrong, sorry for that. But hope you understood my question..

Comment: Thanks. In the interest of understanding the questions and clarify the terminology allow me to ask more details. The product from MuleSoft the link points to is Mule Runtime version 4.2. The example in the link is a Mule Application which consumes a REST API from somewhere else. Please confirm that your question is about an application deployed in AEM trying to consume a REST API *implemented* in a Mule application.

Comment: Hello Aled, my application will be deployed on AEM and will be Posting content to Mule runtime (so Mule will be the one consuming). Hope this helps

Comment: I don't have experience with AEM but this seems to be a generic question of how to invoke a REST API. It doesn't seem to require any Mule specific knowledge. Hopefully that helps some AEM expert to provide an answer.